# Scope issue while creating objects inside if statement if C++

Tags: c++, object, scope

This is supposed to be very basic.

Layout:

```
class handler {
    public:
        handler(Connection *conn) { connection = conn; }
        virtual void handle() = 0;
};

class http_status : public handler {
    public:
        http_status(Connection *conn) : handler(conn) { }
        void handle();
};

class http_photoserver : public handler {
    public:
        http_photoserver(Connection *conn) : handler(conn) { }
        void handle();
};
```

Code:

```
void pick_and_handle() {
  if (connection->http_header.uri_str != "/") {
     http_photoserver handler(connection);
  } else {
     http_status handler(connection);
  }
  handler.handle();
}
```

This gives an error:

```
../handler.cpp:51:10: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
```

I'm guessing because compiler doesn't know what handler is cause object is created inside an if statement. I need to pick a handler based on a condition, how do I do that?

Obviously this code works:

```
  if (connection->http_header.uri_str != "/") {
     http_photoserver handler(connection);
     handler.handle();
  } else {
     http_status handler(connection);
     handler.handle();
  }
```

But doesn't look very sexy! Is it really the only way in c++?

Comment: In this particular case you could just as well do http_photoserver(connection).handle();`

Answer (score 8):

Of course it's not the only way. But you may have to use pointers:

```
void pick_and_handle() {
    unique_ptr<handler> http_handler;
    if (connection->http_header.uri_str != "/")
        http_handler.reset(new http_photoserver(connection));
    else
        http_handler.reset(new http_status(connection));
    http_handler->handle();
}
```

(Instead of `unique_ptr`, you can use `boost::scoped_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, and `auto_ptr` also. But in this case, `unique_ptr` and `boost::scoped_ptr` are most appropriate.)

Comment: +1 : i was writing the same thing. An alternative to unique_ptr would be boost::scoped_ptr.

Comment: @Klaim: Thanks, I've added your suggestion of `boost::scoped_ptr`. :-)

Comment: Your variable name `handler` equals the typename, is that decent?

Comment: @Kerrek: It works, but isn't the best style. I'll update my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Use a pointer so you get polymorphic behavior:

```
auto_ptr<handler> theHandler = (connection->http_header.uri_str != "/") ?
    new http_photoserver(connection) :
    new http_status(connection);
theHandler->handle();
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ can only do polymorphism in pointers and references. Note that with your code, the actual type of `handler` is not known till runtime. The only thing known is that it will be of one of the subtypes of `handler`, so you have to declare a pointer to use the polymorphism:

```
void pick_and_handle() {
  std::auto_ptr<handler> h;
  if (connection->http_header.uri_str != "/") {
     h.reset(new http_photoserver(connection));
  } else {
     h.reset(new http_status(connection));
  }
  h->handle();
}
```

I use `std::auto_ptr` to assure the pointer will be automatically deleted when the function ends.

Comment: You have a memory leak if `h->handle()` throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The object `handler` doesn't exist outside the scope in which its defined.

One solution could be runtime polymorphism, that is, define a base class and a *virtual* function in it, as:

```
struct base_handler
{
   virtual void handle(Connection *conn) = 0;   //interface
   virtual ~base_handler() {}  //must make it virtual!
};
struct http_photoserver  : base_handler
{
     virtual void handle(Connection *conn)  {}  //implementation
};
struct http_status : base_handler
{
     virtual void handle(Connection *conn)  {}  //implementation
};
```

Then use it as:

```
base_handler *phander ; 
if (connection->http_header.uri_str != "/") {
     phandler = new http_photoserver(connection);
} else {
     phandler = new http_status (connection);
}
phandler->handle();
//...
delete phandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a pointer somewhere above that code, and then assign an object later in the if statement. Since they are inherited from the same class, OO teaches us that a child can replace a parent :) .

After that it should work.

Just don't forget to destruct! :)

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with the pointer approach like the others suggest you should also add a virtual destructor the base class.

This approach can be better expressed using a factory method. Just add a static function in your base class that accepts a `connection` and returns a (smart) pointer to a `handler`. Put the "pick" logic there.

If you don't want the pointer approach then the second version you posted is the one to use.